# How do I change "y = ln(x) - ln(y)" into the form "f(x) = u"?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function, eulers-number-e

I tried simplifying the logarithm, I tried adding `ln(y)` to the other side (and negatizing, to subtract `ln(x)` and `y` from both sides), and a whole lot of other stuff. Nothing seems to work. Do you have any ideas?

I originally found this equation from the function `f(x) = xe^x`, and then I realised that inversing that function would let me solve a lot of problems I had unsolved (such as `x^n = n^-x`) that are otherwise seemingly impossible to solve. This is the farthest I got. I suppose you could please the algebra professors of the world and start from `x = ye^y`, but I'm not convinced that that's an efficient solution.

All help is appreciated! Google, wikipedia, and ChatGPT3 were no help, and I don't think anybody's asked this before.

Comment: The inverse of $f(x) = xe^x$ is called the Lambert W function. Also as a tool: ChatGPT is not a good one.

Comment: chatGPT once said any integral that has bounds -inf and inf give 0. don't place your trust in that ;)

Comment: @Max0815 chatGPT once said that $4$ is odd (true story)

Comment: I put ChatGPT in as a joke.

Comment: @SeanRoberson How can I evaluate the Lambert W function in practice?

Comment: @SeanRoberson I know this is a bit beside the point, but I would maintain that ChatGPT3 is an incredible tool, just misapplied in this context. I wouldn't blame a screwdriver for not being able to do my taxes, just not what it's built for.

Comment: Regarding evaluating the W function, there are sum and integral representations for the principal branch, so those may be worth looking into. Failing that, Newton's method would be a good way to go.